# Graph API manage_pages and publish_pages permissions disappearing from an access token's scope

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am using the Graph API to automatically post to a Page. To get a Page Access Token, I have first logged in to my app using the Graph API Explorer's login with the permissions `manage_pages`, `publish_pages` and `pages_show_list`. I then used the access token tool to extend it, then used that to call `me/accounts` in the Explorer to obtain a Page Access token with no expiry time.

When I first logged in to my app, it was in development mode. I looked at the access token in the Access Token Debugger and saw it had the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions. However, when I make the app public, these permissions disappear from the scope of the access token, even though the user it refers to is an Admin of the app. When I try to make an API call in public mode, I get the following error:

`(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permissions manage_pages,publish_pages are deprecated`

This really confuses me, as I believe those permissions have not been deprecated.

Does anyone know why the perms are disappearing/becoming "deprecated" when I switch the app to public mode?

Comment: Because you did not get your app’s use of those permissions reviewed yet …?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

After contacting Facebook, it turns out this is an app verification issue, and the publish_pages permission is available for private test apps, and properly approved public apps.

Answer (score -5):

Sadly manage_pages and publish_pages permissions are deprecated. From their documentation -

> As of April 24,2018, the pubish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the Breaking Changes [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

You can check out [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads) that mentions the above details.

Comment: where does it say `publish_pages` is deprecated? I see the notes on `publish_actions` permission being removed, but can't find anywhere that the same goes for `publish_pages`

Comment: @onassar I've posted a question with details of the process I followed to publish photos from a page and the errors I got. The error message mentions that "the required permissions `manage_pages,publish_pages` are deprecated". You can [check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51022550/8492874).

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look now. @Surdeep Singh

Comment: I never thought `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` where deprecated, I knew `publish_actions` was

Comment: Agreed; very confused about what to be using. From what I understand, they want to deprecate posting to peoples personal profiles, but not to pages. But for the life of me, I can't figure out what permissions to request to allow for page posting.