# facebook sdk error on live app

Tags: laravel, facebook

I have done like this

```
    $appId         = ''; //Facebook App ID
    $appSecret     = ''; //Facebook App Secret
    $redirectURL   = ''; //Callback URL
    $fbPermissions = array('publish_actions'); //Facebook permission
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook(array(
        'app_id' => $appId,
        'app_secret' => $appSecret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    ));
```

and generated long lived access_token.

When i do not publish app my app i can post from website and it will show on facebook page but when i make app live it gives the following error:

```
    "FacebookResponseException in FacebookResponseException.php line 128:
    (#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permissions manage_pages,
    publish_pages are deprecated"
```

while generating access token i have check mark all the permission while getting token.

Comment: What endpoint, what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I want to post on facebook wall from my app as well as on my webiste too

Comment: What endpoint/specific request gives you that error? Do you want to post to a page or a user profile, and if to a page, _as_ the page, or a user?

Comment: i want to post on page as the page

Answer (score 0):

Sadly manage_pages and publish_pages permissions are deprecated. From their documentation -

> As of April 24,2018, the pubish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the Breaking Changes [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

You can check out [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads) that mentions the above details.

Originally answered at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021657/8492874