# How can I post as a Facebook page using API now that publish_actions permission has been deprecated? (since April 24, 2018)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read several tutorials on how to make a Facebook post via Python API. Documentation on [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads) states that -

> As of April 24,2018, the pubish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the [Breaking Changes Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

Still followed the steps:

1. Created a Facebook app
2. Generated a long-lived access token with no expiry limit having all possible permissions I could give to the app (manage_pages, pages_manage_cta, pages_show_list, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, public_profile)

Attempting to Request publish_pages using Graph API Explorer tool leads to this error -

> Invalid Scopes: publish_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

3. Attempted to create a post using the graph API request:

   ```
   curl -i -X POST \
    -d "url=https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" \
    -d "caption=test photo upload" \
    -d "access_token=<user_photos_user_access_token>" \
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/photos"
   ```

This request leads to the following error message -

> This endpoint is deprecated since the required permissions manage_pages,publish_pages are deprecated

Now that publish_pages permission is deprecated, how do I publish a post as a Facebook page using API?

Comment: Does anyone know if it's allowed to post automatic content for the page owner (of course this is his choice to do so or to disable it and it only promotes his own business, so it is definitely content for the facebook page owner)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into the newer API and permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` which you can see in the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-manage_pages).

You need both these permissions to post as a page. Also you need to go through an app review process to get these permissions which is detailed on the [pages docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/).

Edit to answer additional question in comments:
As it says in the linked docs, the tokens expire after an hour and you must request a new one. See bottom of [tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens) page.

Comment: I understand that I need permissions. I'm looking for the steps detailing how I can get the permissions with a non-expiring token.
Is there any way to post without going through the app review process? 
I'm looking to test the app first. The Open Graph access token that still allows me to post is too short-lived. So need a non-expiring token with those permissions.

Comment: Updated answer for your additional question.

Comment: How can I get approval for the permissions if I can't test the permission (even with an admin account or Test User)? And is this only available on certain API versions? (eg. I'm using `2.9` in production, but is this only available to `3.0` or greater?)